# How to access it the persistence variable in authentication on firebase v9 react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my code I'm using the setPersistence function what does it do? and how to access it?

```
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        setUser(userCredential.user.email.split("@")[0]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setError(error.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this note in the docs on [auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)?

> For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser. This is convenient as the user is not required to continuously sign-in every time the web page is visited on the same device.

So the credentials are automatically persisted and restored on most browser environments, which means that you likely don't have to call `setPersistence` yourself, and persistence and restoring the state will work automatically.

To pick up the restored authentication state once the page reloads, you'll want to use an auth state listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on getting the current user:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```